# Java : how to get the active editor in a thread?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin

My problem is the following one : I am working with 2 plugins : let's call them A and B. 
When I start the application, A starts B and gives him a parameter : the current ActiveEditor. B can now perform some actions on the current editor. Everything is fine for this point.  
However, the parameter is given only when A is instantiated, so if the current editor changes, B is not aware of the change. 
I tried to use a Thread, started by A, getting the active editor every two seconds and setting it into B. 
Problem : NullPointerException every time =>

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage() of a null object returned from org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
at com.highdeal.tests.cortex.eclipse.RefreshThread.run(RefreshThread.java:14)
```

Here is the code of the thread started by the plugin A :

```
public class RefreshThread extends Thread {

public void run(){
    while (true){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            IEditorPart iep = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
            new SampleAction(iep);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

When I migrate the following piece of code into the constructor of the Plugin A, it works correctly :

```
IEditorPart iep = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
new SampleAction(iep);
```

Thanks for reading. Ask me if you need further explanations.

Comment: Is SampleAction your plugin B?

BTW this code sample is not enough to arrive at the solution but that wouldn't stop me from saying that this is a very bad way of doing things. You should look up the Observer pattern which is what you should be doing in this case.

Comment: You're right, SampleAction my plugin B. Thank you for the information about Observer Pattern, I will give a look. Fortunately, one of the answer given led me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()` always returns `null` when it is called from a background thread (that is a thread which is not the UI thread).

A better way to do this is to use `IPartListener` to listen for the active part being changed.

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

window.getPartService().addPartListener(part listener);
```

(must be run in the UI thread).

The part listener will be told about each part being activated and you can check if this is a new editor.

Answer (score 1):

To run UI code in other thread instead of UIThread use UIThreadSynchronizer or Display.syncExec()\asyncExec() call.

Comment: Unfortunately this code leads me to something that looks like an infinite loop. Perhaps should I review how do my plugins are communicating in order to make it working